# Error in AppCompatRadioButton setSupportButtonTintList method

Tags: android, android-appcompat, androidx

I have a small problem here. I use android studio 3.6 and have implemented the androidx library.
Minimum api level 16.
I need to change the color of radioButton So I used this:

```
  AppCompatRadioButton rb = new AppCompatRadioButton(context);
  rb.setSupportButtonTintList(colorStateList);
```

When I call the setSupportButtonTintList method, the IDE is showing :

AppCompatRadioButton.setSupportButtonTintList can only be called from within the same library group prefix (referenced groupId=androidx.appcompat  with prefix androidx from groupId=MyAppName)

Answer (score 2):

**Root cause:** From [AppCompatRadioButton](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/appcompat/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatRadioButton.java) source code:

```
/**
 * This should be accessed from {@link androidx.core.widget.CompoundButtonCompat}
 * @hide
 */
@RestrictTo(LIBRARY_GROUP_PREFIX)
@Override
public void setSupportButtonTintList(@Nullable ColorStateList tint) {
    if (mCompoundButtonHelper != null) {
        mCompoundButtonHelper.setSupportButtonTintList(tint);
    }
}
```

This means to call this method from your code, you have two options:

- Access via [CompoundButtonCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/widget/CompoundButtonCompat)
- Access from the same library group prefix, in this case, androidx. But this prefix is reserved for Android.

**Solution:** Access via `CompoundButtonCompat`

```
val rb = AppCompatRadioButton(context)
CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(rb, colorStateList)
```